# Velocity of flue gas

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, velocity

I was wondering on how to calculate velocity of a flue gas which has a gas molecular weight of 28.1544, density of 0.0268 (lb/ft$^3$), temperature of 980˚F, specific heat of 0.2805 (Btu/lb-F), and viscosity of 0.0359. The area of the pipe through which the gas is flowing through is 6 inches.

Is there an equation for velocity that I can use? Can I use the Maxwell Speed Distribution formula to calculate velocity with just the molar mass and temperature of the gas?

Comment: Please show us at least some of your attempts to solve the problem. We can only give you hints and comments on your way of approaching the problem. What do you think about the context of the question? We would like to know what do you know so that we can help you with what you don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You can't calculate the velocity of the flue gas using only the information provided in your post.  You must also know something about the dimensions of the flue through which this gas will be flowing.

Comment: yes sorry i forgot to mention the area